# How can I balance 2 separate LiFePo4 batteries?

Tags: lifepo4, balancing

On my boat I've got devices that run on 24V and others that run on 12V.  Seeing as how the alternator, wind generator and solar panels are all generating 24V, I guess it's fair to say that this is mainly a 24V system.

I have built 3 80AH 24V batteries using LiFePo4 38120 cells, each has its own BMS and these are working just fine.
What do I do about the 12V devices though?

The obvious answer is to use the readily available buck converters, and I am OK with that for most of the 12V requirements (such as instrument displays).
However, I also have a number of bilge pumps that run off 12V and I am not so comfortable with relying on a converter for these.  I would much rather have a 12V battery store running these, to give me a greater safety margin compared with the immediate failure of a broken buck converter.

Before I switched to Li-Ion batteries, I had lead acid batteries.  With 2 batteries in series, I could charge them using the 24V source(s) and then just tap off from one of them to give me the 12V I need for the bilge pumps.  Included in this setup was a battery balancer that kept both batteries balanced, even though I was drawing power from just one of the 12V batteries.
This is an off-the-shelf bit of kit that is widely used in transport applications where additional batteries are used, trucks etc.

Due to the different charge characteristics of Li-Ion vs. lead acid batteries, I don't believe this type of balancer will be suitable to balance Li-Ion batteries since it relies on being able to detect different voltage levels between the 2 batteries in order to do its balancing and Li-Ion maintain full voltage until pretty much empty.

So to my question...

Is there any smart way of performing a similar balancing act between my LiFePo4 batteries?

Thanks.

Comment: The smartest way would be to replace the bilge pumps rated for 24V.

Comment: Yep, I'd already considered that, but it will cost a fair bit of money to purchase 3 large 24V pumps, and I was/still am curious as to whether there is an electronic solution.  Judging by the lack of responses, I'm tending to think that there is no simple electronic solution.